# Is there any shortcut key or menu exists to add php comment block to a php-html individual or mixed block in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, html, phpstorm, keymapping

Before comment:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h2><?php echo $world; ?></h2>
```

After comment:

```
<?php /* ?>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h2><?php echo $world; ?></h2>
<?php */ ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such special commenting style available.

Based on your sample code: you can **use custom Live Template of the surround kind** to wrap your selected lines with opening and closing blocks (it will not add any extra commenting/escaping inside etc).

1. Write such template first
2. Once ready: use it.

---

To create custom Live Template (official docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-live-templates.html):

1. Go to `Settings / Preferences | Editor | Live Templates`
2. Create a group where you will be storing your templates or use existing one
3. Create new Live Template: give it an abbreviation (quick name), description (what this is about), actual template body and applicable contexts and some possible options.

   The body would be:

   ```
   <?php /* ?>
   $SELECTION$
   <?php */ ?>
   ```

   [image]

---

How to use it:

1. Select your code
2. Invoke `Code | Surround with...` (check and use the shortcut that you have got there: it depends on your current Keymap) and use the right one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As @LazyOne rightly mentioned that there is no special commenting option available.

You might consider using `macro` to achieve your goal.

*Steps:*

1. Goto `Edit` -> `Macros` -> `Start macro recording`
2. Type `<?php /* ?>`
3. Go back to `Macros` -> `Stop macro recording`
4. Save as `php open comment` or any other relevant name
5. Repeat step 1 - 3 for `<?php */ ?>`
6. Save as `php close comment`
7. Goto `File`-> `Settings` -> `Keymaps`
8. Inside `Macros` folder you will get both macros, assign appropriate shortcuts
9. Use shortcuts before and after your block of code.